# CLLocationManager crashed with error EXC_BAD_ACCESS under release mode but not debug mode

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access, cllocationmanager, release-mode

My game is always crashing when a location window pops up.

```
-(void) MyFunction
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Whenever it crashes, it returns to main with error **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**. However, I don't receive any stack trace to find out my problem. Neither the zombie provide stack trace.

One interesting thing is, this crash only happens on the iOS Simulator under release mode.
If I change it to debug mode, it works perfectly. If I run it on the devices with release mode, it works perfectly. If I commented out [locationManager startUpdatingLocation], it works perfectly.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using ARC? Check and see if locationManager is being deallocated before startUpdatingLocation

Comment: is locationManager defined with @property (strong) or assign?

Comment: Do you even enter in the delegate methods or you crash inside MyFunction?

Comment: Could you set the Optimization Level to "Fastest, Smallest [-Os]" from your Project -> TARGETS -> [Your Target] -> Build Settings tab -> Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 - Code Generation section, and see if you can reproduce the error from debug mode? Often times, the optimization level hides defects from Debug mode.

Comment: Hello all three: 1. no, it's not deallocated before startUpdatingLocation. 2. locationManager is not defined with @property or assign, it is a regular attribute in my class. 3. I added all the delegate functions; I put breakpoint everywhere so it uses didChangeAuthorizationStatus. However, it always call didFailWithError. And also, thank you all three!

Comment: Hello Jason Huh,: I did what you describe, but the game runs perfectly under debug model without any error. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is a 'regular attribute' that is created without being an @property? That sounds doubtful.